# Correct use of Enum, Button always the same text

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I didn't know where to search for my question, but I am very confused about this.

The premise is: I have one ViewController X that calls ViewController Y and depending on which button is selected in X, I want a different button title for ViewController Y.

In ViewController X, (SSPhotosSelectionView is ViewController Y in this case):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    SSPhotoSelectionViewController *controller = [[SSPhotoSelectionViewController alloc] init];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SelectPhotosSegue"]) {
        if (self.albumsButton.selected) {
           [controller.downloadButton setText:SSPhotosButtonTextAdd];
        }
        else if (self.galleryButton.selected) {
            [controller.downloadButton setText:SSPhotosButtonTextDownload];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, if albumsButton is selected, I want the downloadButton in SSPhotoSelectionViewController to say "Add", otherwise, say "Download".

downloadButton in this case, is a SSPhotosButton object, which is a subclass of UIButton:

SSPhotosButton.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SSPhotosButtonText) {
    SSPhotosButtonTextDownload = 0,
    SSPhotosButtonTextAdd = 1,
};

@interface SSPhotosButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, assign) SSPhotosButtonText text;

- (void)setText:(SSPhotosButtonText)text;

@end
```

SSPhotosButton.m:

```
#import "SSPhotosButton.h"

@implementation SSPhotosButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        if (self.text == SSPhotosButtonTextDownload) {
            [self updateButtonWithText:@"Download"];
        }
        else if (self.text == SSPhotosButtonTextAdd) {
            [self updateButtonWithText:@"Add"];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setText:(SSPhotosButtonText)text {
    _text = text;

    switch (text) {
        case SSPhotosButtonTextDownload:
            [self updateButtonWithText:@"Download"];
            break;

        case SSPhotosButtonTextAdd:
            [self updateButtonWithText:@"Add"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)updateButtonWithText:(NSString *)string {
    self.titleLabel.text = string;
    [self setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.25 alpha:0.5] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}
@end
```

**My problem is**: No matter which button I select, (albumButton or galleryButton), the text is always "Download", never "Add". I suspect I'm doing something wrong in my SSPhotosButton classes, which is SSPhotosButtonText is always 0, which is why it's always SSPhotosButtonTextDownload, but how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `prepareForSeque` you **never** instantiate the destination view controller directly. Instead, you access it via the `segue` parameter:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    SSPhotoSelectionViewController *controller = (SSPhotoSelectionViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SelectPhotosSegue"]) { 
        if (self.albumsButton.selected) {
           [controller.downloadButton setText:SSPhotosButtonTextAdd];
        }
        else if (self.galleryButton.selected) {
            [controller.downloadButton setText:SSPhotosButtonTextDownload];
        }
    }
}
```

Doing it so should set your text correctly.

Comment: Hey thank you for the pointer! I totally forget about this. Now, I'm getting a crash: erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SSNavigationController downloadButton]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12611b800'. I know this is because my SSPhotoSelectionViewController is embed inside a Navigation View Controller?

Comment: In this case it's "pass the value one view controller at a time", meaning in `prepareForSegue` you pass the value to your `SSNavigationController`, and from there (e.g. using a custom property setter or in `viewWillAppear`) to your `SSPhotoSelectionViewController`.